# I am trying to get Facebook posts by using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/statuses"
                     parameters:nil
                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                     completionHandler:^( FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                            id result,
                                            NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"result: %@",result);
                                            }];
```

but it is printing empty

> { data = ( ); }

I used `public_profile`, `email`, `read_stream` as permissions what i need to add more?

Comment: r u get the page post or wall post

Comment: Not possible. Re-check if you have any "status" posted and the app is granted "read_stream" permission. `/statuses` will just give you the statuses, not the links shared etc. To get the complete wall, use `/feed`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik:  wall posts

Comment: @SahilMittal: I have status posted. And Where do i need give read_stream permission for my app. Even if i give feed it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not getting the permission for you app to read the wall.

If you are creating the login control programmatically,

```
FBLoginView *loginView = 
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
        @[@"public_profile", @"read_stream"]];
```

if you're using the `FBLoginView` through Interface Builder you can set the read permissions through the `readPermissions` property of an `FBLoginView` instance:

```
// In your view header file:
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;

// In your viewDidLoad method:
self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"read_stream"];
```

After you get the permission correctly, you will start getting the user's feed with `/me/feed`

---

You can check whether your app has the required permission- https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications . If not, delete your app from this list and re-authenticate with your app.